# select- join having and group by in plsql

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, having

I want number of employees who has worked in 'Furniture' department
I have two tables 
1.department
  dept_id    dept_name
   100  ,      apparels,
   200  ,      furniture,

2.sales
 emp_id , sales_amt , dept_id

I have done this..but it's not showing any result.

```
select count(emp_id) from department a join sales b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id group by dept_id having dept_name='furniture';
```

I know i can use this (as i know for furniture dept_id=200):

```
select count(emp_id) from sales group by dept_id having dept_id=200;
```

but I want to know what is the problem in first code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HAVING** is used to filter rows after the aggregation takes place.
Break down your code:

```
select count(emp_id)
from department a 
join sales b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id 
group by a.dept_id
```

This SQL code only returns a table result with only 1 column, which is the number of employees (`count(emp_id)`). The following HAVING clause (`having dept_name='furniture'`) cannot find `dept_name` column, which results errors.

By changing the selected columns, the following SQL codes could work (depends on your RDBMS):

```
select count(emp_id), dept_name
from department a 
join sales b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id 
group by a.dept_id 
having dept_name= 'furniture'
```

OR using dept_id = 200 condition

```
select count(emp_id), a.dept_id
from department a 
join sales b on a.dept_id = b.dept_id 
group by a.dept_id 
having a.dept_id = 200
```

Comment: Tahnk you for help.